# php script could not run in the user directory

Tags: php, apache2

I use user dir module to setup a homepage for each user. However, the php script can not be executed under each user's html_public folder but could be executed under the /etc/www folder.
What may be the problem?

Comment: More information please.

Answer (score 0):

First of all are you going to the right place in the browser such as domain.com/user1 etc...

Also check permissions.  Other than that you do not have enough information here for anything constructive to be said.

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps have [safe mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php) set in php.ini?  (If so, it needs to be turned off; that feature is deprecated.)